# Quarkus config sources are loaded and invoked multiple times

Tags: java, quarkus, microprofile

We are trying to implement custom `org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource` implementation for AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store(SSM)

Everything works well, but we noticed that configSources are created and invoked 3 times and 3

calls are performed to SSM accordingly(first time during the maven build phase).

We use serverless architecture in AWS with native images and as you can

imagine, multiple calls to the external system are not the desired behavior for us because they affect startup time and cost.

Is it possible to prevent that?

Comment: Can you describe at which moment calls are happening? In the maven build phase, you probably running tests. You won't run the maven build while serverless, because you'll build a native image once

Comment: @DmytroChaban The First time it happens during the build because quarkus is trying to get all configuration for the so-called deployment phase. And two times it happens on the runtime phase and that is strange and to me it looks like a bug. I've created an issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8145